# File Name in log file using log4php

Tags: log4php

I write a wrapper over log4php api named as `loggerimplementation.php`

Now I faced a problem in log files. When I called a function for logging defined in loggerimplementation.

Log file generated as:

```
2011-06-10 10:49:17 [INFO] Log4phpTest: Hello (at C:\xampp\htdocs\logger\Loggerimplementation.php line 74)
2011-06-10 10:50:08 [INFO] Log4phpTest: Hello (at C:\xampp\htdocs\logger\Loggerimplementation.php line 74)
2011-06-10 11:04:01 [INFO] Log4phpTest: Hello (at C:\xampp\htdocs\logger\Loggerimplementation.php line 78)
```

Now , as you can see `%F` will always show wrapper file name because it's always called from there. But I want real file name which one used this wrapper.

So please suggest me the way for this.

Or
tell me from where `%F` details I can get?

Waiting for reply.

Comment: I figure it out:  public function log($message)
       {
               $trace = debug_backtrace();
               $file = $trace[0]['file'];
               $line = $trace[0]['line'];

               $this->logger->info($message . " (at $file line $line)");
       }